# Barcode i25 using ItextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

i am using BarcodeInter25 class to make barcode. I am able to make it but its just blur how can it become more sharp ??
also its background white colour is not completely white
My Code:

```
               BarcodeInter25 code25 = new BarcodeInter25();
               Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(38, 152);
               code25.ChecksumText = false;
               code25.Code = "some digits";
               code25.BarHeight = 2
               System.Drawing.Image i = code25.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White);

               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
               i.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
               Image img = Image.GetInstance(ms.ToArray());
               ms.Dispose();
```

Comment: You're using a lossy image format (JPEG). Blurriness is to be expected.

Comment: I have updated my answer explaining how to make sure that no text is shown (a requirement you omitted in your question). There is no reason to add a barcode as a raster image. As @Phylogenesis indicates: you shouldn't use a lossy image format, especially if there's a way to create a vector image using less lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it should be obvious why the barcode is blurry. You convert it to a `System.Drawing.Image` (making it a raster image) and then you convert it to an `iTextSharp.text.Image` (but by then the image is already blurry).

The correct way to achieve what you want, is to create an `iTextSharp.text.Image` straight from the barcode (do not pass through `System.Drawing.Image`). This can be done like this:

```
BarcodeInter25 code25 = new BarcodeInter25();
Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(38, 152);
code25.ChecksumText = false;
code25.Code = "some digits";
code25.BarHeight = 2;
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
Image img = code25.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
```

Now the `Image` object won't be a raster image (with pixels that make the lines blurry), but it will be a true vector image (no pixels, but instructions such as `moveTo()`, `lineTo()` and `stroke()`). Vector data has the advantage that it is resolution independent: you can zoom in and zoom out as much as you want, it will always be sharp.

This is explained in [Chapter 10 of my book](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=10) where you'll find the [Barcodes](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter10/Barcodes.cs) example. In that chapter, you'll also discover the [`setFont()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/Barcode.html#setFont(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont)) (or in iTextSharp the `Font` property). I quote from the API documentation:

> `public void setFont(BaseFont font)`
>
> > Sets the text font.
> >
> > **Parameters:**
> >
> > `font` - the text font. Set to `null` to suppress any text

So if you don't want to see any text, you can add the following line to the above code snippet:

```
code25.Font = null;
```

Comment: CreateImageWithBarcode
this method also add text but i dont need it, thats why i tried that one

Comment: Please read the documentation if you want to save time. The text of a barcode can be removed by setting the font to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid re-sizing by any means. The output is most likely pixel-perfect but when you scale it up/down a bilinear filter will smooth it rendering it blurry.

I had the same exact problem by embedding a QRC code in a PDF and solved it by avoiding a resize.

If you really need a different size apply it programmatically in code by using the correct [interpolation algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: so how could it achive it, can you give me sample code ??

Comment: It looks like Bruno has given you a working solution. You should try that :)

Comment: yeah he has helped me alot